# firing ondrawitem event of custom combo

Tags: c#

How do I raise a ondraw event
Scenario: I am using a custom combobox with a onDrawItem in my form. 
The drawitem is such

```
 protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {...

        }
Question: How do I make the custom combobox ComboLineStyle redraw
```

itself on selectedindex changed of another cmbBoxLineColor. Ultimately I need a way to redraw all rows of the combobox on every selectedindex changed 
.

```
 private void cmbBoxLineColor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
Here I want the custom combobox-ComboLineStyle  control to redraw itself 


}
```

EDIT
 I need the dropdown to draw itself again when the color in another linecolorcombo changes.Color

```
 lineColorSel = cmbBoxLineColor.SelectedValue;
ComboBoxItemLineStyle itemSolid = new ComboBoxItemLineStyle ("Solid Line", lineColorSel);
```

The color property in my linestylecomboboxitem will have the selectedvalue of the linecolor combo. So the linestyle combo should refresh/invalidate itself and redraw itself with this lineColorSel.

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You can call Invalidate() on anything that inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control to force it to redraw

Heres and example of how I would do a custom draw for a selected item

```
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }

        //or you could do it like this
        //if(e.Index == this.SelectedIndex)
        //{
        //}

        ...

    }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
        base.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: how can I send selected index as a parameter when I Invalidate/Refresh    ComboBoxItem item1Solid = new ComboBoxItem("Solid Line", selectedIndex).then redraw using the selectedindex

Comment: you shouldn't have to. you can tell if your OnDrawItem is drawing a selected item by checking the DrawItemEventArg.State

Comment: Invalidate/Refresh dont seem to redraw the control. And even if they do, they dont have the selected item.

Comment: I am not sure if you got the question correctly. Onselectionchanged of another linecolor combo, this one the linestylecombo should update itself.

Comment: So, to paraphrase, you want to have one combo box where the user can select a color, and you want it to be able to change the line color of some other combo box? Then why not put a public LineColor Property on your color changing combo box, such that, when set also Calls Invalidate/base.OnDraw. Then just get the LineColor in you OnItemDraw method.